# Cannot resolve React when importing a module

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I installed material-UI and I'm trying to import a button and it's throwing me an error.

The code (inside my index.js file in client folder) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Launcher } from '../../src'
import messageHistory from './messageHistory';
import Highlight from "react-highlight.js";
import './../assets/styles'
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

error:

```
 ERROR  in ../~/@material-ui/core/Button/Button.js
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in `'C:\Users\dale.grant\Desktop\hyberchat-chat-service\node_modules\@material-ui\core\Button'`
```

And it says this about 11 times just with different parts such as Button/ripple.js

One thing I've noticed is I have a package-json and a package-lock.json for this client side and for my server side, and the material-ui is inside the package-lock.json for my server side? Anyway, I've tried deleting the node-modules etc a few times and restarting them.

Not sure if I've missed something? I created the app from 'react-chat-window'
not sure if that is 'create-react-app' but I think it is?

I also tried installing material-ui while inside my client folder too.

The client is run by web-pack and server just normal node.

package.json: 
 `"dependencies": {
    "emoji-js": "3.2.2",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-highlight.js": "1.0.5",
    "socket.io-client": "2.0.3"`

also the client package.json:

```
"body-parser": "^1.18.3",
"dialogflow": "^0.7.0",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"nodemon": "^1.18.4",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"socket.io": "^2.1.1"
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that you've installed `material-ui` dependency

You can install it by running `npm install @material-ui/core` command

After that you can use it in your project

Comment: So I did install it but did I not do it as dependency? whats the difference? also I have a client and a server both with their own package.json and package-lock.json - does this mean I install it in the main project folder, one of these two or both of them?

Comment: It should be installed in the client part of a project since you will be using this library for rendering a button. You are missing the material-ui on client side, just install it and it is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that react dependency is added in package.json.

Comment: Added it !     Please see above